# Azure Data Factory - iterating multiple data set option

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I request your support for the following clarification,
I have a scenario where to read data from multiple HubSpot portals (for example Chile, Peru, Colombia, etc.,) through Azure Data Factory.
It’s a simple copy operation from HubSpot to Azure SQL Server, but I stuck up with iterating single copy activity for above the mentioned multiple region portals.
I have created a separate dataset for each region but not sure how to iterate that with Copy Activity.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show what you have tried!

Answer (score 1):

Data Factory supports a [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) operation. You can wrap Data Factory sub-processes (ex. *Copy Activity*) within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to make your source dynamical in copy activity. As far as I know, this is not supported now.